# Problema de permissão com XAMPP

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

Instalei o XAMPP no ubuntu, porém não consigo fazer uma simples instalação do wordpress. Já apontei a pasta de projetos que no caso era:

**/opt/lampp/httdocs**

para (pasta pessoal):

**/ronald/workspace/www**

Já dei permissão 777 para a pasta lampp, mesmo assim nada.
Já mudei o grupo, que antigamente era root para o user ronald, mas também nada.

Enfim... Pesquisei muito e até agora não obtive resultado. Acredito que seja uma besteira, mas se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Mas qual problema que ocorre?

Comment: @JoãoPedroAlves como falei, acredito que não estou conseguindo fazer uma simples instalação (wordpess) por conta de permissão das pastas.

Comment: Mas o que aparece na tela?

Comment: Um exemplo seria a não permissão para renomear o arquivo wp-config-sample.php. Com isso a instalação consegue proceder...